# Excel VBA macro from one cell to multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

This macro works if you apply to one cell at a time (or if you drag across multiple rows, will work on the row of the top-left-most cell). Is there a way I can further tweak it to get my macro to apply the changes to the rows of all selected cells so that the user can make changes to rows in bulk?

I recorded a macro that will split what exist as one row into 8 rows for the last `columns J:Q`
My logic was to insert 7 rows above a selected cell (which exist below the cell that will be merged) and then merge the rows with the original existing row for `columns A:I`

This will give me one cell for `A:I` and 8 rows for `J:Row` End

```
*See macro below



Sub splitrowsandmerge()
'
' splitrowsandmerge Macro
' add 7 rows and merge 8 rows for first 9 columns
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A8").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
     .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
End Sub
```

Comment: I think we need a little more information on what you mean by selecting multiple rows. So if you select A1 and B5, you want it to run from A1 and B5 but have the same result with the different columns?

Comment: The first problem that you are having is that you are using "ActiveCell".  ActiveCell is only 1 cell and is defined as the upper-left most cell in the selected cells.  You want to use "Selection." instead of "ActiveCell."

Comment: The second problem that you may have is if the user selects a disjointed range.  To get past this, use the split function: rangeArray = Split(Selection.Address,",") and then loop through the Array.

Comment: Once you get the rows, loop through them BACKWARDS, so that you don't change the row numbers of the ones above it.  Then you can modify the code that you've provided to do the desired merging.

Comment: I'm not particularly in the mood to write the code, and it will be instructive for you to do it yourself.  If you get stuck on a specific part, feel free to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few adjustments to make more sense of this code and make it much easier to read through. This doesn't answer your original question as I need a little more information to understand what you trying to do. But this should help myself and others read through your code easier.

I made a guess at what you were looking for and pasted some code that should work for you, if you want every column from A to I in the row you select to be merged with the 7 inserted rows below.

```
    Sub splitrowsandmerge()
'
' splitrowsandmerge Macro
' add 7 rows and merge 8 rows for first 9 columns
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'

Dim RowArray() As Integer

check = 0

For Each cell In Selection
    If firstTime <> 1 Then
        ReDim RowArray(0) As Integer
        RowArray(0) = cell.Row
        firstTime = 1
    Else

        For i = LBound(RowArray) To UBound(RowArray)
            If RowArray(i) = cell.Row Then
                check = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If check <> 1 Then
            addOne = addOne + 1
            ReDim Preserve RowArray(addOne) As Integer
            RowArray(addOne) = cell.Row
        End If

        check = 0
    End If
Next cell

RowArray = BubbleSrt(RowArray, False)
For i = LBound(RowArray) To UBound(RowArray)

    startCell = RowArray(i)
    Rows(startCell + 1).EntireRow.Resize(7).Insert

    With Range(Cells(startCell, 1), Cells(startCell + 7, 9))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    For j = 1 To 9
        Range(Cells(startCell, j), Cells(startCell + 7, j)).Merge
    Next j
Next i

End Sub

Public Function BubbleSrt(ArrayIn, Ascending As Boolean)

Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


If Ascending = True Then
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) > ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
Else
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) < ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
End If

BubbleSrt = ArrayIn

End Function
```

Comment: Currently I have one row with data. I would like to have one cell for columns A:I and 8 cells for colums J:Q relative to the one cell in A:I              Example: On a blank work sheet if I merged cells A1:A8 repeated the process through column I, I would have my result.

Comment: So you want A1:A8 to be merged for instance and every column through I to be the same way? I'm confused about what you mean for J:Q.

Comment: Correct for A1:A8 to be merged. I used the inserting rows technique because I need to apply this to over 100 rows that already have data.

Comment: Could you provide a before and after screenshot of what you are trying to do? I am a little confused about the J:Q part of your comment. Also with the code I provided it will add the rows and merge A:I on whatever rows are selected.

Comment: What 163:170 look like is what row 171 will look like after my marco is applied. It works when one cell is selected but would like it to work when multiple cells are selected.

Comment: Would you be selecting cells in the same row? That would make the code not work correctly for what I posted, I would have to weed out duplicate rows to get that to work.

Comment: I think I can explain this much simpler. 1. Select row 1 . 2. Insert 7 rows. 3. Merge cells for A1:A8 (Repeat for B1:I8). Done. Repeat. Select Row 9 insert 7 rows. Select A:9:A17 merge cells (Repeat for B9:I17)

Comment: I need to select cells in same column not row

Comment: I think I understand what you are wanting with J:Q, took me a few times of reading over your post and comments to make sense of it. Sounds like you just want J:Q to not be merged like A:I. Have you tried using the code in my above answer? It should work as you have asked, for every cell you select, it will merge A:I and add the 7 rows below the selected cell.

Comment: I updated my post with a lot more code, this was a fun little project that had a few challenges. I was able to use some code I've used before to get it to work. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Worked! Thank You Histerical

Comment: You bet! Good luck with your future programming, Excel is a fun tool. Don't forget to mark the answer.